# How to configure ESLint to understand Vue.js v-model directive?

Tags: vue.js, eslint, false-positive

Let's have a sample single file Component:

```html
<template>
  <InputComponent v-model="foo" />
</template>

<script setup>
let foo = 1
</script>
```

ESLint says:
`ESLint: 'foo' is never reassigned. Use 'const' instead. (prefer-const)`

However since it is used in a v-model directive it is used in a read-write context, it should be okay.

I have installed `eslint-plugin-vue` and has the parser set to `vue-eslint-parser` in my `.eslintrc.` but somehow it does not seem to understand what is going on with the `v-model` directive.

How to configure ESLint to understand Vue.js v-model directive?

Comment: It should be considered reassigned, since it is used as the model variable of a component which will update the value, thus it is let and not const.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Vue documentation actually a const should be used, because primitive types should be declared by the [`ref()`](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html#ref) helper which returns a proxy which in turn will not be reassigned.
So probably the proper code is like this:

```html
<template>
  <InputComponent v-model="foo" />
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'
const foo = ref(1)
</script>
```